# Dropdown list to custom Action bar

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I am using custom Action bar https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar but I am not able to implement the dropdown list on some action butoon. Is it possible to implement the list into this Action bar?

I need something like this:
[Action bar dropdown list](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/dropdown-dark.png)

Comment: You might consider using ActionBarSherlock, which has this feature, the same as the native action bar.

Comment: I already checked the Sherlock action bar, but the posted one is more simple.

Comment: if you want to develop Actionbar like in your image & this is good for  performance wise & more convenient option where @commmonWare is suggested.

Comment: "the posted one is more simple" -- then do not complain when it does not offer features that you want.